# How to display selected text of multiselect dropdown in label using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap Multiselect dropdown`. I want to display selected text in label. If I unselect the element should remove from label.

When I select this element should display in label,

[image]

Code tried so far:

```
$('#AttendeeLists').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true });
```

Comment: Please provide what have you done so far. Thanks!

Comment: $('#AttendeeLists').multiselect({
                enableFiltering: true,
                includeSelectAllOption: true });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution which I found to work in my case**

```
$('#multiselect1').multiselect({
    selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: '300',
    buttonWidth: '235',
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
        var brands = $('#multiselect1 option:selected');
        var selected = [];
        $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
            selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });

        console.log(selected);
    }
});
```